# How to use THREE.JSONLoader after R99

Tags: three.js

Now the JSONLoader had been removed, how could I load the models that loaded by JSONLoader before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `JSONLoader` was removed from `three.js` with `R99`. But the loader is still available as [LegacyJSONLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r110/examples/js/loaders/deprecated/LegacyJSONLoader.js). If you include the file into your project, you can create an instance of `LegacyJSONLoader` and load your JSON model as before.

Keep in mind that you are using an obsolete JSON format. You might want to consider to export your models to `glTF` via [GLTFExporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/exporters/GLTFExporter.js) in order to use a future-proof 3D format. The following example demonstrates the usage of the mentioned exporter:

https://threejs.org/examples/misc_exporter_gltf.html

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Looking now it seems the files have been removed. Where can I find it now?

Comment: You have to checkout `R110` and copy over the loader. `LegacyJSONLoader` and `LegacyGLTFLoader` were completely removed with `R111`. In any event, you rally shouldn't use these loaders anymore. Try to convert your legacy assets to something more recent like `glTF`.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectLoader` is available and it works as `JSONLoader`

Comment: Please expand your answer and explain it.